# Laravel 7.2.* Language string parameter is not translating with the given value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am having a weird problem working with language parameters in laravel. It is not being replaced with the variable but outputting the entire key.

## admin.php

```
return [
    ...
    'delete_title' => 'Delete :item',
    ...

    // user section
    'user'          => [
        'user'            => 'User',
        ...
    ],
];
```

## view.blade.php

```
// this won't work
{__('admin.delete_title', ['item', 'User'])}}

// this won't work
{__('admin.delete_title', [':item', 'User'])}}

// this won't work
{__('admin.delete_title', ['item', __('admin.user.user')])}}

// this won't work
{__('admin.delete_title', ['item', __('admin.user.user')])}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should to pass correct args to translate function try:

```
{__('admin.delete_title', ['item'=>'User'])}}
```

Comment: This is damn silly mistake. I now realized I am setting up value as another item of the array. Really damn stupid mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to pass parameters as array, so:

   ```
   {{ __('admin.delete_title', ['item' => __('admin.user.user')]) }}
   ```
2. You have typo in

   ```
   'delete_title => 'Delete :item', // missing '
   ```

   fixed:

   ```
   'delete_title' => 'Delete :item',
   ```

Comment: I realized my stupid mistake where I have set the value as another item in the array. So stupid mistake. 
The typo happened while posting a question and not in the file itself.
Thank you!